# Problems with plot after for

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I have a problem plotting these sentences

```
for Temp = 1:3
   for Veg = 1:3
   z = Temp * Veg;     
   end
end

x = 1:9;
plot(x,z)
```

I want to plot the values of `z` but I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to give `z` an index:

```
for Temp = 1:3
   for Veg = 1:3
      z((Temp-1)*3+Veg) = Temp*Veg;
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it a bit faster, produces the same result:

```
z = (1:3)'*(1:3);
z = z(:)';
```